# How do we know who is moving?

Tags: acceleration, inertial-frames, relativity, observers, equivalence-principle

If I am in a free float environment and there is another object at rest relative to me, and then I start to accelerate towards this object, do I know I am the one who is moving, since I am the one who is feeling the acceleration? If I accelerate and then start to coast at a constant speed, can I conclude that the object did not move and that the one who was moving was me, since I felt the acceleration?

Answer (score 0):

In that environment, you can always tell if you are the one experiencing an acceleration because during your acceleration, you will experience a force that you can feel. So if you keep track of that force (with an instrument called an *accelerometer*) while also keeping track of the distance between you and the other object, then you can tell which of you is accelerating.

Comment: @PM2Ring, I did not look at them, thinking that I'd answer the question as an exercise for myself. If it offendith, I shall delete.

Comment: Thanks for that. How does one move an answer to the "dupe target"?

Comment: You have to do it manually, by copying & pasting, then deleting the original.